# How to execute a script when I start Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I would like to execute a script when I launch Android Studio (eg npm update -g and flutter upgrade). Is it possible, and if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Startup Tasks for this -

- File > Settings.
- In the settings window, search for "Startup Tasks" using the search bar.
- Click on "Edit Custom VM Options" and a dialog box will appear.
- Add the following line at the end of the file, replacing the path with the path to your script:

  *`-Didea.executable.launcher.<SOME_UNIQUE_ID>=/path/to/your/script`*
- Save & Restart Android Studio.